# Show TimePicker but not as a pop-up or dialog on the form page

Tags: flutter, datepicker, frontend, flutter-layout

[image: TimePicker]

[image: Form Screen]

[image: Options available]

I have to achieve this UI!
But this is part of the page (form).
How can I add this TimePicker as a Widget to Column of the page and have access to its picked time.

```
   SizedBox(
   width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.44,
   child: FittedBox(
      child: TimePickerDialog(
      initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
      initialEntryMode: TimePickerEntryMode.input,
      ),
    ),
   )
```